# Helios: can not register device id for push notifications in production mode

Tags: ios, notifications, push, unicorn, helios

I have an helios application with both my push notitifications certificates (development and production) located on the same machine. When I run in development mode, with the following line in the config.ru file.
"service :push_notification, apn_certificate: '/home/ec2-user/app_development.pem', apn_environment: 'development' 
everything works fine, I can send push notifications without any issues.

However, when we replace that line with a production certificate and the production environment:
service :push_notification, apn_certificate: '/home/ec2-user/kickoff_production.pem', apn_environment: 'production'
registering device ids no longer works.

I have no clue why this happens. When I open the helios admin panel (localhost:5000/admin), I can see the deviceIds that were registered under development mode.

The file ProcFile contains the following line: "web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -E production".

I really don't know what I can do to fix this. I hope someone can help me. Thanks very much!

Comment: @can you guide me how to register device in development mode? I installed helios on local server.